# Get vCPU count for a given AWS instance type in Go using AWS client

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2

I've the AWS instance type(e.g. `c5.18xlarge` etc.) in my config files. During runtime, I would like to fetch the number of vCPUs(e.g. `72`) from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/cpu-options-supported-instances-values.html and do some computations and launch instances based on the number of vCPUs.
I can store this data from the [webpage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/cpu-options-supported-instances-values.html) in a map and refer the map, but is there a way to fetch this information from AWS using AWS go client?

Comment: why do you want to get vCPU specifically from AWS go client?  I mean by using `runtime.NumCPU()` you can get the information

Comment: @Manjeet The instance where my code will be running is not the same as the instance I'm getting from the config file. My code will launch AWS instances of that instance type after doing some validations on instance type

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DescribeInstanceTypes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceTypes.html)

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2"
)

func main() {
    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("eu-west-1")},
    )

    svc := ec2.New(sess)

    resp, _ := svc.DescribeInstanceTypes(&ec2.DescribeInstanceTypesInput{})

    for _, v := range resp.InstanceTypes {
        fmt.Println(*v.InstanceType, v.VCpuInfo)
    }

}
```